# Group By with Concatenation in Sub Query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to write an SQL query which will return a column of ID numbers for results, of which each team of people only appears with their best time.

In essence, it is a system which allows people to put in times for a relay event (like a swimming event with 4 team members), and will only show the best time for that team.

[SQL Fiddle:](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffff3)

The only thing I can think of is doing a Group By on result.id and having a field which is GROUP_CONCAT(member_result.member_id ORDER BY member_result.member_id). I can then group on this, but then I get stuck.

Suggestions are very welcome.

---

As an aside, for non-relay events, this is the code I am using:

```
SELECT result_id FROM ( 
    SELECT member_id,MIN(time) AS mintime 
    FROM result 
    JOIN member_result ON result.id = member_result.result_id 
    WHERE event_id = ? 
    GROUP BY member_id 
    ORDER BY mintime
) AS x 
JOIN result ON result.time = x.mintime 
JOIN member_result ON member_result.result_id = result.id AND member_result.member_id = x.member_id AND event_id = ? 
GROUP BY member_result.member_id ORDER BY mintime
```

Comment: How do you identify that members are on the same team?

Comment: @MostyMostacho updated fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ed41

Expected result is just a list of ID numbers relating to the best times each different combination of people has achieved for a specific event - e.g. in the Fiddle example, result 2 would be shown for that team of people [1000,1001,1002] as the time they achieved was better (quicker) than the time they achieved previously.

a team can be identified by them all being linked to the same result (i.e. in example) 1000,1001,1002 are a team as they competed together to form result 1 and result 2.

Comment: It is VERY difficult (if it is even possible) to solve that query. This is because there is no way to know to which team a result corresponds to nor which team a member is part of. If there was only 1 result for each team, this would be ok, as you would be using the result as a way to identify a team. However, taking it as you say "A team can be identified by them all being linked to the same result", then the "team" linked to result 1 is different from the "team" linked to result 2, however, they share the same member IDs, which would be consufing. Did I explain my self?

Comment: I was wondering if a team identifier could be generated, for example a function (excuse that wording) which aggregated the multiple rows which comprised a team into an identifier - in the Fiddle example above, one which aggregated into 1000/1001/1002 for example. Grouping could then be done on this aggregated identifier?

Comment: At first sight it is possible... of course, team 1000,1001,1002 would be different that team 1000,1001, but it would mean compensating a design flaw with unfriendly code in all subsequent queries. The team should not be a calculated field, it should be stored in the DB.

Comment: Can you provide the desired result for that fiddle?